# Prime decomposition in algebraic integer rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathcal{O}_K \subset \mathcal{O}_L$ be algebraic integer rings and $\theta \in \mathcal{O}_L$ such that $L=K( \theta )$. Let $\mathfrak{F}_\theta$ be the unique maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_L$ contained in $\mathcal{O}_K[\theta]$. We know that if a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is prime to $\mathfrak{F}_\theta$, then we can get the prime decomposition of $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\mathcal{O}_L$ using the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ over $K$.

My question is that is there any conclusion saying that we can get the prime decomposition of all primes of $\mathcal{O}_K$ using this method by changing the $\theta$.

Comment: [Dedekind example of a non-monogenic field](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/154Page/handouts/nonprim.pdf) says that sometimes there is some prime $\mathfrak{p}$ such that no $\theta$ yields $O_K[\theta]/\mathfrak{p}\cong O_L/\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Can you expand on "the unique maximal ideal of $O_L$ contained in $O_K[\theta]$" ?

Comment: This handout proves that $p | [\mathcal{O}_K : \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]$ for any integral primitive element $\alpha$, but $\mathcal{O}_K[\theta] / \mathfrak{p} \cong \mathcal{O}_L / \mathfrak{p}$ can be satisfied by a weaker condition, that is $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime to the "unique maximal ideal". This ideal is the unique maximal element of $\{ \mathfrak{a}  \mid \mathfrak{a} \subset \mathcal{O}_K[\theta] \text{ and } \mathfrak{a} \text{ is an ideal of }  \mathcal{O}_L \}$.

Comment: Actually, these two conditions are equivalent in this example. So in general, the answer is no.

Comment: $I = \{ a\in O_K[\theta], a O_L\subset  O_K[\theta]\}$ is the largest $O_L$-ideal contained in $O_K[\theta]$, doesn't have to be maximal.

Comment: My "maximal" means your "largest", but I don't know this representation of the conductor. Thank you.

Comment: @yuan Might I recommend carefully writing up what you've learned and answering your own question? This is a very natural question to ask after learning about Dedekind's theorem, but it is often not discussed, and I'm sure others would benefit from a careful explanation of what you've discovered! (It will also remove your question from the 'unanswered' list.)

Answer (score 0):

First let me clarify what the $\mathfrak{F}_\theta$ is. $\mathfrak{F}_\theta=\{ \alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K[\theta] \mid \alpha \mathcal{O}_L \subset \mathcal{O}_K[\theta] \}$ is the largest ideal of $\mathcal{O}_L$ contained in $\mathcal{O}_K[\theta]$.

Then, if $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}$, the condition $p$ prime to $\mathfrak{F}_\theta$ is equivalent to $p \nmid |\mathcal{O}_L/\mathbb{Z}[\theta]|$. For the necessity, if $p$ is prime to $\mathfrak{F}_\theta$, then $p \nmid |\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{F}_\theta |$. Hence $p \nmid |\mathcal{O}_L/\mathbb{Z}[\theta]|$ since $|\mathcal{O}_L/\mathbb{Z}[\theta]| \mid |\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{F}_\theta |$. For the sufficiency, if  $p \nmid |\mathcal{O}_L/\mathbb{Z}[\theta]|$, then the map from $\mathcal{O}_L/\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ to itself which sends every element to its multiple by $p$ is an isomorphism of the additive group. Then $p \mathcal{O}_K + \mathbb{Z}[\theta]=\mathcal{O}_K$. Therefore, $p \mathcal{O}_K + \mathfrak{F}_\theta=\mathcal{O}_K$, that is, $p$ prime to $\mathfrak{F}_\theta$.

Next is our counterexample. Let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ where $\theta^3+\theta^2-2\theta+8=0$. As in the handout mentioned above, $2 \mid |\mathcal{O}_L/\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] |$ for every integral primitive element $\alpha$. Hence $2$ cannot be decomposed using this method in $\mathcal{O}_L$.
This shows that the general answer is NO. As mentioned in the handout, the prime decomposition lies somewhat deeper than factoring in $\mathbb{F}_q[X]$.